# Counting characters in a string and setting a boolean to T or F based on parameters

Tags: java, for-loop

Working on a homework question and I cannot understand why one of the tests is not working.

Here is the question:

Declare a Boolean variable named goodPassword. Use goodPassword to output "Valid" if checkStr contains fewer than 6 digits and checkStr's length is less than or equal to 10. Otherwise, output "Invalid".

Ex: If the input is `SDhm3650F8`, then the output is:

Valid

Ex: If the input is `BrgFSyDGk4j`, then the output is:

Invalid

Once compiled the program runs 10 test cases for the loop and all but one of them is coming back successful. Been confused as to why it isn't working for a while now and cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidInvalid {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String checkStr;
      Boolean goodPassword=true;
      int i;
      int counter=0;
  
      checkStr = scnr.nextLine();

      for (i = 0; i < checkStr.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(i)) {
               counter = counter + 1;
            }
       }
  
      if (checkStr.length() > 10) {
         goodPassword = false;
      }
     
         else if (counter <=6){
            goodPassword = true;
            }
  

      if (goodPassword) {
         System.out.println("Valid");
       }
      else {
          System.out.println("Invalid");
       }
   }
 }
```

Here is a sample of the results I'm getting. Number 5 is the one that keeps failing.

```
3: Compare output
Input
RPCTFSJ2W
Your output
Valid

4: Compare output
Input
xnqd9bkcgwtsr
Your output
Invalid

5: Compare output
Output differs. See highlights below.
Input
63198207s
Your output
Valid
Expected output
Invalid your text
```

Comment: They say "fewer than 6 digits", but you have `<= 6`. Second, as James already said, `goodPassword` is initially `true`, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Your test `if (Character.isDigit(i)) {` should be `if (Character.isDigit(checkStr.charAt(i))) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test `if (Character.isDigit(i)) {` should be `if (Character.isDigit(checkStr.charAt(i))) {`.

Also, replace:

```
     else if (counter <=6){
        goodPassword = true;
        }
```

with:

```
     if (counter >= 6){
        goodPassword = false;
        }
```

You can also replace both tests:

```
  if (checkStr.length() > 10) {
     goodPassword = false;
  }
 
     else if (counter <=6){
        goodPassword = true;
        }
```

with:

```
  if (counter >= 6 || checkStr.length() > 10) {
     goodPassword = false;
  }
```

Or even:

```
goodPassword = counter < 6 && checkStr.length() <= 10;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your code , i think the initial value of goodPassword should be false.

Better is initialize goodPassword  to fasle.
Set the goodPassword to true only if the counter is less then 6 and checkStr.length() is less than 10 . Both checks in a single if condition using '&&'

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321217/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

## Code point, not `char`

Avoid using `char`. That 16-bit type is legacy, physically incapable of representing most characters. The `char` methods can fail. For example, try `"".length()`.

To work with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

```
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray() ;

if ( codePoints.length > 10 ) { return false ; }  // Must be ten or less characters.

int countDigits = 0 ; 
for( int codePoint : codePoints ) 
{
    if ( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) ) { countDigits ++ ; }
}
return ( countDigits < 6 ) ; // Must have fewer than six digits.
```

When you get comfortable with streams, we can shorten this to two lines.

```java
public static boolean isValidPassword( String input ) 
{
    if ( input.codePoints ( ).toArray ( ).length > 10 ) return false;
    return input.codePoints ( ).filter ( Character :: isDigit ).count ( ) < 6;
}
```

I would think you should also check for empty string, or a string filled with [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

```
if( input.isBlank() ) return false ;
```

---

Regarding `Character.isDigit`, be aware that Unicode defines many other digits besides the 0-9 in US-ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your code can be improved and optimized.

1. The loop implemented for digit counting does not accurately validate the presence of digits within the input text. Evaluate the characters within the string rather than their respective places. Instead of utilising the method `Character.isDigit(i)`,use `Character.isDigit(checkStr.charAt(i))**`.
2. Make a comparison between the variable "**counter**" and the value 6 in order to ascertain whether there exists a quantity of digits that is less than six, and then evaluate the length of the string "**checkStr**" by invoking the method "**length()**" and comparing the result to the value 10, so as to determine if the length is less than or equal to ten.
   Here's the working code. I checked it. Hope it helps .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidInvalid {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String checkStr;
      Boolean goodPassword=true;
      int i;
      int counter=0;
  
      checkStr = scnr.nextLine();

      for (i = 0; i < checkStr.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(checkStr.charAt(i))) {
               counter = counter + 1;
            }
       }
       //  Check the two conditions simultaneously, optimize
       if (counter < 6 && checkStr.length() <= 10 ){
            goodPassword = true;
            }
      else goodPassword = false;
 
      if (goodPassword) {
         System.out.println("Valid");
       }
      else {
          System.out.println("Invalid");
       }
   }
 }
```